# Select distinct values (2 or more) in Core Data (Objective-C, iPhone, Xcode)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

How to make this SQLite query in Core Data (iOS developing)?

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE_1, VALUE_2 FROM TABLE;
```

It should returns (duo, trio) of distinct values, for example, from this table:

```
(123, 234, Car)
(123, 456, Bus)
(234, 456, Train)
(123, 456, Eletric Bus)
(234, 456, Subway)
```

It should returns 3 rows because `(123, 234)` is UNIQUE and so `(234, 456)` and `(123, 456)`.

```
(123, 234, Car)
(234, 456, Train) or (234, 456, Subway)
(123, 456, Eletric Bus) or (123, 456, Bus)
```

With this code I can DISTINCT only ONE value:

```
NSDictionary *entityProperties = [entity propertiesByName];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"VALUE_1"]]];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify more that one unique property to fetch:

```
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"VALUE_1", @"VALUE_2"]];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

(Note that you can give a list of attribute names instead of property
descriptions.)

This should return an array of dictionaries like this:

```
[
   { "VALUE_1" = 123; "VALUE_2" = 234},
   { "VALUE_1" = 234; "VALUE_2" = 456},
   { "VALUE_1" = 123; "VALUE_2" = 456},
]
```

However, there is no way (that I know of) to make the fetch request additionally
return the third attribute from a "randomly chosen" object.

Comment: Using a list of 2 attributes works great! But as you said, I have to make another request to get the third value. It sucks! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Fabio: Another possible solution *could be* to set `[request setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[@"VALUE_1", @"VALUE_2"]]` instead of `setPropertiesToFetch`. You would get all objects, but grouped by value_1/value_2, so that you can pick the first or any object. But I am not 100% sure and cannot test this at the moment.

Comment: Hi Martin, I tried with setPropertiesToGroupBy but I couldn't make it! Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey @Martin, do you know if it's possible to retrieve different results like { "VALUE_1" = 123; "VALUE_2" = 234} is the same of { "VALUE_1" = 234; "VALUE_2" = 123}. If I group by OR use distinct values, I get {123, 234} and {234,123} as different values (that should be) but I would like to group by: X+Y or Y+X. Thanks for any help!